# How to append child to parent with simiilar attribute?

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have two UL with list items,
they have the same attribute, as example data-id. But when page is loading, they are not append to the same UL.

So, I need some way to move it correct.
Probably it's strange description,
example:

```
<!-- HOW IT LOOKS AFTER PAGE LOAD -->
<ul data-id="first_ul">
   <li data-id="first_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="second_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="second_ul"></li>
</ul>

<ul data-id="second_ul">
   <li data-id="first_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="second_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="first_ul"></li>
</ul>

<!-- HOW IT SHOULD LOOKS AFTER SCRIPT'S WORK -->
<ul data-id="first_ul">
   <li data-id="first_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="first_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="first_ul"></li>
</ul>

<ul data-id="second_ul">
   <li data-id="second_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="second_ul"></li>
   <li data-id="second_ul"></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: _when page is loading, they are not append to the same UL_ . If this is a problem, why don't you fix it on server itself.

Comment: Something like I have no access to the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('ul[data-id] li').each(function(){
   $(this).appendTo('ul[data-id="'+ this.dataset.id + '"]');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3VAy6/

Comment: Or http://jsfiddle.net/3VAy6/2/ (to make the results visible). +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
   $('ul[data-id="'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'"]').append($(this))
})
```